# How to get certain things from POST

Tags: django, post

How do I retrieve things from post that match a wild card? Or maybe there is a better way?

I want this to magically work, so e and i are dictionaries with keys and values from post.

```
e = request.POST.get(u'e_*')
i = request.POST.get(u'i_*')
```

request.POST could look like...

```
<QueryDict: {u'e_3': [u'9'], u'e_2': [u'5'], u'e_1': [u'3'], u'e_4': [u'2'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'Ig2UF7As7Qa2iaEqIBSlX2ziWW7Grxtw'], u'i_3': [u'8'], u'i_2': [u'11'], u'i_1': [u'10']}>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It won't magically work . you have to create custom form with `prefix` . and get post request like : `GeneralForm(request.POST, prefix='e_')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dictionary comprehensions like:

```
e = {k:v for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'e_'}
i = {k:v for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'i_'}
```

Comment: I also ended up sorting it and putting it in a list of tuples... `e = sorted([(v, k) for k,v in request.POST.items() if k[:2] == 'e_'], key=itemgetter(1))` thank you